# WPF How to get Width of a Panel dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, width

Hi I have an empty Panel, and want to add items to it at runtime. I also want to make sure that panel's Width doesn't extend the window's Width, If so I want o add items in other panel.

In my XAML :

```
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,5,0" Padding="2" Background="LightYellow" 
      BorderBrush="SteelBlue" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3"  >
        <StackPanel Name="legendsPanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <DockPanel  Name="legendsPnl1">                    
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel  Name="legendsPnl2">
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

In code behind :

```
        int legendSize = 30;    // W for 1 Legend

    private void AddLegend(string title, double value, Brush clr)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("SP - " + legendsPanel.ActualHeight.ToString() + " DP - " + legendsPnl1.ActualHeight.ToString());  // 0, 0

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Width = 10; rect.Height = 10; rect.Fill = clr;

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Content = title + value;

        /* 
         * Here, before adding to legendsPnl1 I want to make sure that it's W =  (W + legendSize) <= legendsPanelWidth
         * legendsPanel - > StackPanel i.e. Parent of legendsPnl1
         * Width of legendsPanel, Grid, Window all are in wither Stretch mode or free Width - Auto or *, 
         * so can't make out how to get the W of them. At runtime, their W, ActualWidth are shown either 0, NaN, null
         */
        legendsPnl1.Children.Add(rect);
        legendsPnl1.Children.Add(lbl);

    }
```

How to find legendsPnl1 panel hasenough space to add both elements (of size legendSize var ) , else add the elements in legendsPnl1  panel ????

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use a WrapPanel instead?

Comment: How big would you expect an empty `Panel` that you *didn't* provide dimensions for to be? I would *hope* that it had no size. I can't quite work out *why* you would want to do what you're doing... I'm *sure* there's a much easier way using XAML. In WPF, we simply have no need for these kinds of calculations... just define the right XAML and let it look after itself.

Comment: OH Clemens, Thanks a lot. Replacing StackPanel to WrapPanel & removing DockPanel helped me achieve exactly what I wanted to. Thanks a lot. Can you add yuor Comment as an Answer, so I can mark it as answer. Thanks once again.